# Importing a file that imports another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I would like to import a file that also imports another file.

I currently have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── foo
    ├── file1.py
    ├── file2.py
    └── file3.py
```

With the following code:

```py
# main.py
from foo.file1 import func1

func1()


# foo/file1.py
from file2 import func2
from file3 import func3

def func1():
   # Do stuff
   func2()
   func3()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # Do some other stuff
   func1()


# foo/file2.py
from file3 import func3

def func2():
   # Do stuff
   func3()


# foo/file3.py
def func3():
   # Do stuff
```

If I run `main.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'`.

I could replace the line `from file2 import func2` in `foo/file1.py` with `from foo.file2 import func2` and do the same for the file3 import but then I could not run `foo/file1.py` on its own.

What would be the recommended way to fix this?

Comment: Make sure `foo` is a module. You might need to put an empty `__init__.py` file in there.

Answer (score 1):

**`Python3` doesn't support `Implicit Relative Imports` e.g. `from file2 import func2`, we need to use `Explicit Relative Imports` e.g. `from .file2 import func2`.**

---

In `foo/file1.py` change:

```
from file2 import func2
from file3 import func3
```

To:

```
from .file2 import func2
from .file3 import func3
```

And in `foo/file2.py` change:

```
from file3 import func3
```

To:

```
from .file3 import func3
```

---

You might want to read: [Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

Comment: If I do this and run `main.py` from `.` it will work but then I can't run on `file1.py` on its own. My question is how to make it possible to run `file1.py` on it's own from `foo` and also be able to run `main.py`?