# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class2' when trying to import a file that imports another file

Tags: python, file, import

I have a directory structure like:

[image: File Structure]

In `main.py`, I try `import classes.class1`, and then in `class1.py` I try `import class2`.

When I run `class1.py` directly, it imports class2 successfully. However, when I try to run `main.py` instead, I get an exception that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class2'`.

It seems like the `main` module cannot see `class2`. I can't understand the error. Shouldn't it be `class1` that is importing `class2`, not `main`?

How can I fix the problem?

I thought that when a file was imported, it would see the file that would be in its directory, rather than having to rely on the .py file that calls the function from another directory.

I also tried the approach described in [Importing a file that imports another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388427), but then I get an error that says `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: Create a file name ```__init__.py``` in classes directory (folder).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply. I tried doing that, but it still gives me the error. I created an __init__.py as told to. However, am I supposed to leave that blank?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea no, that has **nothing to do with the problem**. This is a very common piece of misinformation.

Comment: OP: when you try running `main.py`, what is the current working directory? Exactly what command do you use? Similarly for `class1.py`. Do you see how this is relevant to the problem?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see, yes. However, I tried putting an init .py and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Questions about `import` in Python are asked constantly, and the canonicals are a mess that are not helpful for new users even though immense effort has been put into them and even though the concepts are really not that hard. It would be better if we could start them all over (and I am sort of trying to organize that effort). In the mean time, use the relative import described in the question you found, and then see the duplicate I linked to fix it (or at least, to understand what you changed such that it works now. I guarantee `__init__.py` has nothing to do with it).

Comment: Unless, of course, are using an ancient version of Python (3.2 or earlier). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ohh. You are right! Just using the relative import works fine!!! I wonder why it did not work before when It tried it, mustve been doing something wrong. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Most likely for one of the reasons explained in the linked duplicate.